# Recording a Call in PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Are there any Plugins available for Recording a Call in Android using PhoneGap? Or some guidance on how to implement it!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is possible at all. I *hope* the phone will protect the calls from beeing recorded by any app.

This is not a matter of phonegap.

**edit**
I found some apps, that can record calls at android phones.

Basicly it would be like audiorecording:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html

The only thing would be to detect the phonestate. Now the trouble  may start, because your app is send to background and *maybe* will be paused.

Answer (score 0):

There's not one that I can find.

Here's the documentation on creating a plugin for phonegap 3.x:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide

And here's a tutorial on writing a plugin for phonegap 3.x:
http://devgirl.org/2013/09/17/how-to-write-a-phonegap-3-0-plugin-for-android/

You'll need to have this file stucture

```
src
    android
    ios
www
plugin.xml
```

You can also put more platform folders inside of src depending on which ones you want to support. plugin.xml includes all of the instructions for phonegap to be able to automatically install the plugin for each supported platform.

Here is an example of a plugin that's been upgraded to Phonegap 3.x.